# JavaScript : Printing Dynamic value/data

Tags: javascript

This is sample JSON I got `{"valueofa" : 1234}`.To print the value it is something like  `body.valueofa`. However, this `valueofa` can be anything like `apple` or something else. So to parse that I object I had tried with `${body}.${value}` which isn't working and it's shouldn't be. How can I set the variable with body. So that I can parse the body whatever the value is.

Comment: Which body are you referring to? Also, where would you use the syntax ${body}.${value}?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your object always contains only one key value pair like shown in the question, and you don't care about the key, you can just use Object.values()

```js
console.log(Object.values({"valueofa" : 1234})[0]);
console.log(Object.values({"apple" : 1234})[0]);
```

The same is true for objects holding multiple key value pairs, Object.values() will return an array of all the values in your object if you omit accessing the first element with `[0]`

Answer (score 0):

You can access a value of JSON using square brackets.

```
var value = "valueofa";
body[value];
```